# How to not have the query params in the URL

Tags: php, url, url-shortener

I'm not really sure if that question made any sense, but basically, if I had a link like this:

```
site.com/?id=1HLk83I
```

How do URL shortening services turn the URL into:

```
site.com/1HLk83I
```

If you did it like the first URL, you would get that info by using GET and finding 'id'. I have no clue how they do it or if they even do, do that.

I'm not completely sure if I'm even asking the right thing here. I'm just wondering how you can get info from the URL (1HLk83I) and then be able to use it in your code.

Comment: Generally by rewriting it back into `site.com/?id=1HLk83I` behind the scenes - URLs are all smoke and mirrors.

Comment: Deleted my comment by accident.

Comment: How could you turn that into an actual working url then?

Comment: Heh - and I deleted my comment since you deleted yours... you couldn't really turn that into a functional URL (if you're referring to an URL shortening service); that `id` string would mean something in *their* system, it would probably link to the proper full domain in their database - in yours it would just be a meaningless string as you don't have the corresponding back-end data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .htaccess file rewrite rule:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Then you can access that in index.php file:

```php
echo $_GET['id'];
```